# SOAPUI - Different data source for two different properties in the same Request

Tags: soapui

I have a request having the following properties:
`field1`, `field2`, `field3` and `field4`.
I have created a data source of 100 records for `field1`, `field2` and `field3`.
Now for the field 4 i need to give input of 500 email IDs.

for eg., I need to create records as below;

```
field1value1, field2value1, field3value1, field4email1  
field1value1, field2value1, field3value1, field4email2
```

How do I do this in SOAPUI PRO?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a testcase with two datasources, one for field1-3 and one for field4.
In the request you can fetch field1-3 from the first datasource and field4 from the second datasource.

[image: datasource loop]